# how to abort the network request when the code has already entered the curl_easy_perform()

Tags: c++, curl

I want to abort it immediately, for some reason. However, i couldn't find a good way to realize it yet. Can it be that: threadA abort a network request that was created in threadB?

Comment: Please explain your problem briefly. You can include related codes, screenshot or error log. So, stack community respond more appropriate on your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it with easy interface. Use [multi interface](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-multi.html) instead. It allows you to know when interface is ready to perform IO operations without blocking.

Answer (score 0):

options include, but are not limited to, returning non-zero from CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION or the CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, which results in CURLE_ABORTED_BY_CALLBACK - or returning bogus data from CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION which results in CURLE_WRITE_ERROR , all of which aborts curl_easy_perform()